# .md5mesh - multiple meshes with smooth normals

Tags: mesh, normals, md5mesh

I have a .md5mesh which contains multiple meshes and I want to calculate smooth normals. The normals are correct but they don't work with multiple meshes.

My first idea was to merge all meshes, then calculate the normals and then render them seperated again, but I'm afraid that something will go wrong with this.

I already tested merging the meshes with blender and it gives me correct normals, but breaks texturing because each mesh has it's own texture.

I need advice on what to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is struggling with the same problem, here is my solution:

I concat all indexed meshes into one mesh and then create smooth normals for it one time. Afterwards I can use these normals for each individual mesh.

This simple idea gave me blender, where you have to keep reference to a joined smooth shaded mesh to get smooth normals for each splitted mesh.